# Show the direct sum is a proper subset of the direct product.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

I searched all the posts on the direct sum and direct product, and found the following explanation:

For a finite number of factors, the direct sum and direct product of abelian groups (and more generally, of R-modules) are equal.

However, when you have an infinite number of summands/factors, the two constructions are different. Explicitly, the direct product
$$\prod_{i∈I}A_i$$
is the collection of all functions $f:I→∪A_i$ with $f(i)∈A_i$ for each $i$ (you can think of them as the "tuples" indexed by $i$, with the $i$th coordinate being the value $f(i)$).

But the direct sum
$$\bigoplus_{i∈I} A_i$$
is the collection of all functions $f:I→∪A_i$ with:

1. $f(i)∈A_i$ for each $i$; and
2. $f(i)=0$ for all except perhaps a finite number of $i$.

That is, the direct sum is the subgroup/submodule of the direct product that consists of the almost-null elements. When there are only finitely many coordinates, saying "all are zero except perhaps for a finite number of coordinates" is the same as saying nothing.

Question) What I can't see is the number 2 condition for the direct sum. Can anybody explain how to show 2?

Comment: It's a definition, there's nothing to show.

Comment: @peoplepower How so? Abelian groups is $R=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For the question in the title, just notice that with an infinite index set infinitely many coordinates can be nonzero, so you get an element of the product that is not an element of the sum.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @TrevorWilson That's what I don't get it.  I see that infinitely many coordinates can be nonzero. But, what element of the product cannot be an element of the sum is bothering me. For example, $x\in R^\infty$, $x=(t,t,\dots)=(t,0,\dots)+(0,t,\dots)+\dots$?

Comment: I assume the $t$ is nonzero and "..." means that you continue to infinity.  In this case, $(t,t,\ldots)$ is not an element of the direct sum.  It doesn't meet the definition because infinitely many coordinates are nonzero.  Moreover, on the right hand side you seem to have some kind of infinitary addition going on.  But such an operation is not defined. There is no sensible definition---what would $(1,0,0,\ldots) + (1,0,0,\ldots) + (1,0,0,\ldots) + \cdots$ be?

Comment: Adding an infinite number of terms together in an arbitrary module is generally impermissible. It can only ever be allowed in either a formal or topological sense in certain cases, and even then the situation must be defined so that the structure is *closed* under these infinitary operations; the direct sum cannot be closed under arbitrary sums.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations. I thought the infinite sum very naively.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, that the direct sum of (left, say) $R$-modules is the subset of the direct product consisting of elements which are $0$ in all but finitely many coordinates is the **definition** of the direct sum.

But you can still ask *why* this definition is given.  A popular and useful answer is that the direct sum -- defined this way! -- satisfies a universal mapping property which establishes that it is the [coproduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) in the category of left $R$-modules.  Similarly 
the direct product is the [product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29) in the category of left $R$-modules.  The fact that direct sums and direct products coincide when the index set is finite is an instance of the categorical notion of **biproduct** and in fact holds in any **additive category**.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As an self starter for the mathematics, I want to know a good basic introductory book. Any recommendation?