# Understanding the direct product and direct sum in Abelian Groups as the categorial union.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

I was required to show that for $G \in \textbf{Ab}$, where $\textbf{Ab}$ is the Abelian Group Category, one can build the categorial union of an arbitrary family $\{G_i\}_{i \in I} \subset \textbf{Ab}$.

There are two very similar groups that one can build: the direct product and the direct sum. If $I$ is finite, both the product and the sum are equal and there's nothing to think about.

But suppose that $I$ is infinity. Thus, the direct sum is strictly a subgroup of the direct product.

Why is the direct sum the categorial union and not the direct product? If I'm not missing something, both are non-empty, since $(e,e,e,\cdots)$ is there, both are closed under products and inverses when we define the product $\circ$ as $(f \circ g)(i) = f(i)g(i)$?

I mean, why we can sum infinitely non-trivial elements finitely times, but we cannot sum infinitely non-trivial elements infinitely times?

Accordingly to [Lee's Mosher answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525213/a-difficulty-in-understanding-the-definition-of-a-direct-sum-and-direct-product/2525289#2525289):

"But in the direct sum $\oplus_{i \in I} A_i$, there *is* a further restriction on $f$: all but finitely many coordinates must be the zero element. In other words $f$ must satisfy the following property: there exists a finite subset $J \subset I$ such that if $i \in I-J$ then $f(i)$ is the zero element of $A_i$.

[...]

However, in the case of an infinite index set such as $I = \mathbb{Z}_+$, we can easily write down an element $f$ which is in the direct product but not in the direct sum: simply assign $f(1)$ to be a nonzero element of $A_1$, and assign $f(2)$ to be a nonzero element of $A_2$, and generally for any index $i \in I$ assign $f(i)$ to be a nonzero element of $A_i$."

but it seems to me enough to justify this issue.

Comment: What is the definition of a categorical union? Is it that what is usually called the categorical **sum** or **coproduct**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me put it this way. Fix an infinite set $J$ and Abelian groups $(A_j)_{j\in J}$.

> Why is the direct sum a coproduct, but the direct product is not?

Given an Abelian group $G$ and a family of homs $f_j:A_j\to G$, there is a clear well defined hom $\bigoplus_{j\in J}A_j\to G$ extending the $f_j$ that also satisfies uniqueness. You should know this so I won't dwell on it; great. What goes wrong with direct product (using the obvious attempt of inclusion maps)? Well, it's very simple. We would have to define $f:\prod_{j\in J}A_j\to G$ as $f((a_j)_{j\in J}):=\sum_{j\in J}f(a_j)$ ... and this expression doesn't actually make sense in $G$ as the group axioms do not guarantee a notion of infinite sum.

> Why is the direct product a product but the direct sum is not?

So you should know the product is a product; great. With the direct sum, we would have to define the map $f:G\to\bigoplus_{j\in J}A_j$ as $f(g)=(f_j(g))_{j\in J}$... but this only makes sense in the direct sum if all but finitely many $f_j(g)$ are zero, which really has no reason to be true in general. So the natural attempt at making $\bigoplus_{j\in J}$ a categorical product fails. And it cannot succeed in general because this would imply an isomorphism $\bigoplus_{j\in J}\cong\prod_{j\in J}$ which isn't generally true.

Comment: Thanks mate! Really appreciate the clarification.